# SwiftUI View Reading a Property with an Async Action

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am building an app where I need to change the SwiftUI View based on a bool property. The problem is that boolean property value depends on the result of an async operation.

```
 Label("\(tweet.likeCount)", systemImage: isTweetLiked ? "heart.fill": "heart")

 private var isTweetLiked: Bool {
        Task {
            return await model.isTweetLikedByCurrentUser(tweet: tweet)
        }
    }

Cannot convert return expression of type 'Task<Bool, Never>' to return type 'Bool'
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is `Label` in a `List` or `ForEach`? If yes get the value in the model for each item. If no make `isTweetLiked` a `@State` and get the value in the `.task` modifier

Comment: Yes It is inside a List. The main issue is that the isTweetLiked property calls the async method on model as shown above. And that does not work when returning values.

Comment: You might load once a list of the liked tweets (or the ids of the tweets) of the current user. Then you can synchronously check against the id. Or maintain the ids directly in the data model.

Comment: could you try one thing bind isTweetLiked to a state property of Boolean type, and set it after the result of await model.isTweetLikedByCurrentUser(tweet: tweet) is available. Should fix it I believe.

Comment: @saketkumar model.isTweetLikedByCurrentUser is an async function so I am not sure where to call It repeatedly.

Comment: I am coming up with a code snippet, hold on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only provide limited insight from the code reference you have given.

Here, you would have to wait for async operation to complete then you can change the state of the property to which properties of Label might be binded.

I tested this code locally, It works.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var likeCount: Int = 0
@State var isTweetLiked: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    Label("\(likeCount)", systemImage: isTweetLiked ? "heart.fill": "heart").onAppear{
        Task {
            await updateUsers()
        }
    }
}

func updateUsers() async {
    do {
        let isLiked = await model.isTweetLikedByCurrentUser(tweet: tweet)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            likeCount = isLiked ? likeCount + 1 : isLiked
            isTweetLiked = isLiked
        }
    } catch {
        print("Oops!")
    }
}
}
```

Certainly, I tested with a sample API, but I have changed the code to resemble your code for ease of understanding.

Also, I am calling the updateUsers from onAppear. Which might not be what you want, you can call it from a place which suits your custom requirements.

Comment: Thanks! In my code I can tap on the heart and change the likeCount and fill the heart of unfill it. This means for me onAppear only fires once when the page is loaded.

Comment: You can call updateUsers on button tap action, no?

Comment: Thanks! Yes trying to figure out where to correctly call it. Thanks for your help! definitely puts me on the right track.